# Separation between logic gate inputs

Tags: latex, tikz

How can I increase the separation between the inputs of the logic gates using `tikz`. I can solve this problem by using multiple inputs if they are available. However, when only two inputs are possible, then I can't use this method. This leads to problem of overlapping labels.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.US}
\tikzstyle{branch}=[fill,shape=circle,minimum size=3pt,inner sep=0pt]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit logic US]
  \node[xnor gate] at (0,0) (xnor) {};
  \node[label={left:$A$}] at ([xshift=-1cm]xnor.input 1) (A) {};
  \node[label={left:$B$}] at ([xshift=-1cm]xnor.input 2) (B) {};
  \draw (A) -- (xnor.input 1);
  \draw (B) -- (xnor.input 2);
  \node[label={right:$Y$}] at ([xshift=1cm]xnor.output) (Y) {};
  \draw (xnor.output) -- (Y);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I cannot use `circuitikz` package for some reasons.
In the following figure, I don't want A and B to overlap on each other.
I understand that I can shift the levels up and down and then they won't overlap on each other.

Comment: Hi! Remember to mark the answer below as accepted, if it solved the problem! :)

Answer (score 1):

Having helped myself reading pages 240 and 586 of the [PGF Man­ual](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), I advise to try

```latex
\node[label={[above] left:$A$}] at ([xshift=-1cm]xnor.input 1) (A) {};
\node[label={[below] left:$B$}] at ([xshift=-1cm]xnor.input 2) (B) {};
```

or

```latex
\node[label={[above left] $A$}] at ([xshift=-1cm]xnor.input 1) (A) {};
\node[label={[below left] $B$}] at ([xshift=-1cm]xnor.input 2) (B) {};
```

Another variation:

```latex
\node[label={[yshift=1mm] left:$A$}] at ([xshift=-1cm]xnor.input 1) (A) {};
\node[label={[yshift=-1mm] left:$B$}] at ([xshift=-1cm]xnor.input 2) (B) {};
```

This produces the following output (similar to the previous two):

[image: screenshot of output pdf]